# Nil when obtain coordinates in swift

Tags: ios, swift, location

I am trying to abstain coordinates from the device, but the app crash. Anyone know what might have happened?
I suppose the error happened when it asked for permission but the request was denied, maybe creating an if statement it works, but I couldn't find any information about that.

output:`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

```
import UIKit  
import Foundation  
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
 let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("\(locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude), \(locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude)")
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() // Ask for Authorisation from the User.

    // For use in foreground

    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
    {

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
    var latitudeactual:Double = 0
    var longitudeactual:Double = 0

    latitudeactual = locValue.latitude
    longitudeactual = locValue.longitude

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if latitudeactual != 0 || longitudeactual != 0 {
        latitudeactual = locValue.latitude
        longitudeactual = locValue.longitude

        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `location` property is an implicitly unwrapped `CLLocation` optional, and it is likely `nil`. You should never access members of implicitly unwrapped optional unless you know it is not `nil`. You can confirm it is `nil` with the following:

```
if locationManager.location != nil {
    println("\(locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude), \(locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude)")
} else {
    println("locationManager.location is nil")
}
```

Or you could just:

```
println("\(locationManager.location)")
```

But don't try to access the properties of an implicitly unwrapped object without first checking to see if it's `nil` or not.

---

As a general rule, you should not expect a valid `CLLocation` object for the `location` property unless location services were started and location updates have already started to come in (e.g. you've seen `didUpdateLocations` called). The process of determining location happens asynchronously and is not to be expected to be available in `viewDidLoad`. One should put location-specific logic inside the `didUpdateLocations` method.