# Users lat long in ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager

How can the users current latitude and longitude values be referenced in the viewDidLoad method?

I've tried using the following, but...

```
   let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad()    
{
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.delegate = self
        let locationLong = locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude
        ...
```

I don't think the locationManager has had a chance to obtain the value before the code runs and it fails with the message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: If you don't know how to use a class, why don't you read it's documentation?

Comment: getting users location can take seconds, so yes it is nil when you try to access the value on the main thread...

Comment: You need to use `CLLocationManager` delegate method to get coordinate, what you are doing it wrong. Read Doc.

Comment: What we're trying to do is show users directions to a destination as soon as the application opens up.  Is there a way to do that where it's not on the main thread or is somehow dependent upon the CCLocationManager finishing figuring out the users location?

Comment: It should work , did you add the location permission request in plist ??

Comment: Yes, the location permission request was added.  What I'm attempting to do probably doesn't belong in the viewDidLoad method (not sure), but I don't know how else to accomplish what we're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer I was looking for here:

[Nil when obtain coordinates in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829573/nil-when-obtain-coordinates-in-swift)

> As a general rule, you should not expect a valid CLLocation object for the location property unless location services were started and location updates have already started to come in (e.g. you've seen didUpdateLocations called). The process of determining location happens asynchronously and is not to be expected to be available in viewDidLoad. One should put location-specific logic inside the didUpdateLocations method.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. Hope this is work for you. Thanks

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.delegate = self
}

// CLLocationManager Delegate Method
func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:AnyObject[]) {
      //Use manager for latitude and longitude
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  We're attempting to access the lat and long values in the viewDidLoad method.  It sounds like that isn't an optimal way to do it, but I don't know how else to show the user directions as soon as the app opens up.